# django-rest-auth registration/account-confirm-email/ how to use it to verify the user

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth

I have used django allauth for user sign up and once the user registers, an email with the following url is sent to the user:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/registration/account-confirm-email/MTY:1ggGpL:n8gHmRfOzgjR2vZTHopxiUkCe-w/

according to this: 
https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/issues/292

"You should override this view/url to handle it in your API client somehow...",

but my question apart from overriding is that how this string "MTY:1ggGpL:n8gHmRfOzgjR2vZTHopxiUkCe-w/" in the sent email can be used to validate the email,

Thanks,

Comment: I am in a somehow similar situation right now, I don't know wow to confirm email using Django rest auth. please can you share any pointer?